# Pandas dataframe .loc with else condition

Tags: pandas

I would like to set a condition in the dataframe for every row that says if value of columnA = 1 then `df['outcome']` is 'Yes' and if not then 'No'

So something like this: `df.loc[df['columnA']=1,'outcome']='Yes' else 'No'`

Comment: `df['outcome']=df['columnA'].eq(1).map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})`

Comment: also you can use loc 2 times if you wish

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use np.where

```
import numpy as np
df['outcome'] = np.where(df['columnA'] == 1, 'Yes', 'No')
```